# Missing parameter in web service C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, wcf

I am creating a web service in C#:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void upd(string id, string upddate,string pm)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updcsuv", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    SqlParameter[] param =
    {
        new SqlParameter("@id",id),
        new SqlParameter("@upddate",upddate),
        new SqlParameter("@username",pm)

    };
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

and the stored procedure for the web service is

```
CREATE proc updcsuv             
    (@id int,              
     @upddate datetime,              
     @username varchar(30))              
as              
begin            
    update csuv              
    set date = @upddate,              
        UserName = @username,
    where 
        id = @id              
end
```

I am getting the error in my web service and I don't understand why the error is happening as I think my web service is correct and I passed all the parameters correctly

This is the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: upddate.
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: On which line you receive this exception ?

Comment: `upddate`

`new SqlParameter("@upddate",upddate),` this line

Comment: @mybirthname...

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said your problem line is `new SqlParameter("@upddate",upddate).` So you are specified in your query params that `upddate` is `datetime` type. But you are giving string to it. So this can create a problem, also I suppose your string is empty and you forgot to add your `DateTime` which you create before that.

```
if (upddate.ToString() == "")
{
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-1900", enGB);
}
else
{
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date, enGB);
}

//when you go to the params, set dt for upddate instead of your string.
SqlParameter[] param =
{
    new SqlParameter("@id",id),
    new SqlParameter("@upddate",dt),
    ....
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want the update date, you should just write is like this:

```
if (upddate.ToString() == "")
{
    dt = DateTime.Now;-> this will return you current date, which will be the update date !
}
```

Comment: but when i change the code to this

`//store procedure
@date datetime,              
set date=@date,
And change all the parameter from upddate to date`

it starts working but i want to use upddate